# Launch screen via storyboard, how to specify images for different device sizes?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, assets

In my iOS app, I'm using a storyboard for my launch screen. Of course in that storyboard, I reference an image from my assets catalogue.

I'm wanting to be as efficient as possible to save space in my binary and thus use as few images as possible. In theory, I'd like to use one image for iPhone XS, XS Max, XR, X, one for 5.5 inch and 4.7 inch iPhone devices, one for 4 inch iPhone devices, and one for iPad.

Problem is, I don't know how to tell the assets catalogue to reference these different images? It only gives me options for 3x, 2x iPhone and 2x iPad.

Now if I don't do my launch image from a storyboard and you use the "Launch Image" asset instead, it has specific slots for each device, but of course then I have to use like 7-8 different images (i.e. if i use one for XS Max, it won't scale for XR, XS, and X).

Is there a way I can reference image sizes for specific devices using a storyboard so I can be more efficient?

Comment: I believe your launch image size differs for all the screen sizes, in that case use vector graphics. iphone support 1x 2x 3x fixed size images

Comment: @InderKumarRathore In this case I can't, it's a splashy launch image done in something like photoshop.

Comment: screenshot please bot of your launch storyboard and simulator

Comment: If you are going to use a storyboard then you need to pick one image and use `aspectFill` mode; Part of the image will "bleed" offscreen on some devices, so you need to ensure the important information is in the center and the off-screen content doesn't matter

Comment: @InderKumarRathore appreciate your help, i actually decided to use the LaunchImage asset instead of the storyboard just because I forgot about app thinning and it won't have as big of an impact as I assumed.

Comment: @Paulw11 good point i forgot it's dynamic now because of storyboard.